# OpenCvSharp Mat.Set does not give expected result

Tags: python, c#, opencv

Note: These questions are about [OpenCVSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) v3.1.20160114.

**Question 1.**

As in below example, I expect a red square but result is a black with weird color stripes.

```
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var mat = new Mat(300, 300, MatType.CV_8UC3, Scalar.White);
        for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
            for (int j = 100; j < 200; j++)
                mat.Set(i, j, Scalar.Red);
        Cv2.ImShow("red square", mat);
        Cv2.WaitKey();
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

I edit `Scalar.Red` to `16711680` (#FF0000 in integer) and it works. Is this expected behavior? or a bug in OpenCvSharp?

**Question 2.**

why multiple-vertical-stripe-colors at the right side of the box? As I turned to red square, It still has yellow color at the right side.

**Weired yellow strip at the right side**

[image]

**Question 3.**

Python can access each channel and set value(color) as below.

```
mat.itemset((pixel[1], pixel[0], 2), 255) # Red channel to 255.
```

Is there any similar method in OpenCvSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you're trying to set the color of a 3 channel image at once. If you follow the code in the URL or the snippet below I think all 3 of your questions are answered.

I followed these instructions and didn't have any problems.
https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/wiki/Accessing-Pixel

```
//Option1
var mat = new Mat(300, 300, MatType.CV_8UC3, Scalar.White);
for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
    for (int j = 100; j < 200; j++)
    {
        Vec3b color = mat.Get<Vec3b>(i, j);
        color.Item0 = 0;
        color.Item1 = 0;
        color.Item2 = 255;
        mat.Set<Vec3b>(i, j, color);
        //mat.Set(i, j, Scalar.Red);
    }
Cv2.ImShow("red square", mat);
Cv2.WaitKey();
}

//Option2
var mat = new Mat(300, 300, MatType.CV_8UC3, Scalar.White);
var indexer = mat.GetGenericIndexer<Vec3b>();
for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
    for (int j = 100; j < 200; j++)
    {
        Vec3b color = mat.Get<Vec3b>(i, j);
        color.Item0 = 0;
        color.Item1 = 0;
        color.Item2 = 255;
        indexer[i, j] = color;
    }
Cv2.ImShow("red square", mat);
Cv2.WaitKey();
}
```

This code shows two of the three options in the URL above that document pixel level access in OpenCvSharp.